# How large matrix can be fit into Eigen library?

Tags: matlab, out-of-memory, bigdata, eigen3

I am working on large scale data like 300000 x 300000 matrix currently may interest. It is really hard to process in matlab due to "Out of memory" error so I decide to use EIGEN. Is there any restriciton for eigen in the matrix size?

Comment: possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449434/eigen-max-matrix-size-for-32-bit-applications

Comment: but it is not, at least my machine is 64 bit server

Comment: In MATLAB you would need `300000*300000*(8 bytes) to GB ~ 671 GB` to store that data in memory, otherwise you will start swapping on disk and that might take a while (definitely days).

Comment: Have you tried the top answer? (Recommendation to ask Eigen directly if you need support). Also, have you tried using the sparseness?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dense matrices in EIGEN are stored in a contiguous block of memory, which cannot exceed 2 GB in 32-bit application, so if you're running a 32-bit application, the allocation will start to crash for matrices half this size, that is to say around 10,000x10,000. See for example [this duplicated question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3449434/eigen-max-matrix-size-for-32-bit-applications?lq=1).

The same issue will happen with other libraries, since you're bounded by your RAM, not by the library.

Yet, if your big matrix has a vast majority of 0 in it, you can resort to [SparseMatrix](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/group__TutorialSparse.html).

If your matrix isn't sparse, then you may store it on disk, but you'll get terrible performance when manipulating it.